# GUI wallet cannot send

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

My Monero GUI wallet cannot send! I've tried repeatedly on different computers, tried restoring wallet, it crashes or gives the message "Can't create transaction: Unexpected error: Call method failed." What is wrong?? Using latest GUI wallet (monero-gui-install-win-x64-v0.17.1.9.exe) connected to Trezor Model T on Windows 10. Is all my XMR frozen forever???

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug present in the Trezor code that causes the GUI to crash occasionally whilst trying to send. This will be fixed in the upcoming release. See:

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/7330

In the meantime, please try sending a smaller amount of the balance.

Comment: I still get the same error when trying to send Monero using Trezor Model T with release 0.17.2.0

Comment: @NilsBreitmann -  Were you running any other wallet software concurrently?

Comment: Yes, I had my Exodus wallet running to copy the target address. I tried it again without Exodus and it worked. Great! Thanks a lot!